# Add or Delete Subscription - Azure

Tags: azure

I searched for a way to set up a configuration that will send me an email when I add a new subscription or delete an existing one but I didn't find what I need. I need help from an expert in Azure, please.

What i did till now :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean about subscriber?  subscription?

Comment: yes sorry  i mean subscription

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up a configuration that will send an email when add or delete the subscription, you could setup an Activity Log alert to receive email, SMS, or webhook notifications when an activity occurs that match your alert conditions.

For the details, you could refer to [Audit and receive notifications about important actions in your Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-quick-audit-notify-action-in-subscription).

Comment: can you explain more about it ?

Comment: So which of your double postings is the answer? This question is off topic and will be closed soon anyway so you shouldn't be answering it at all but please combine your answers into one that solves the problem. Both cannot be the answer!

Comment: @Rob why this question is off topic ??

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Portal, find **Monitor** in the **All services**, and then in the monitor blade, open **Alter** and add **New alter rule**. In the Create rule page, you could set up the rule that you want about the subscription.

[image]

Comment: how can we share pictures under this question ?

Comment: Cannot share pictures in a comment. In the Question, you can click the picture symbol to upload the picture.

Comment: check the question please , i added new picture